# Почему в RoR не удаётся вызвать методы подключенных js плагинов?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Доброго времени суток!
Дано:

- RoR 5.0.2
- установленные

  ```
  gem 'clockpicker-rails' 
  gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
  ```

  `application.js`:

  ```
  //= require jquery
  //= require bootstrap
  //= require smoothscroll
  //= require bootstrap/clockpicker
  //= require bootstrap-datepicker
  //= require rails.validations
  //= require rails.validations.simple_form
  //= require turbolinks
  //= require_tree .
  ```
- Скрипт, в котором произвожу вызовы:
- Элемент списка

  ```
  ready = ->
    $('.clockpicker').clockpicker
    $('.datepicker-inline').datepicker
  $(document).ready(ready)
  $(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready)
  ```

В консоли ошибок нет никаких. В консоли браузера при попытке выполнения кода, например:

```
$('.datepicker-inline').datepicker();
```

получаю ошибку

```
TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
```

Гем для datepicker вот https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails

Там в руководстве по использованию есть два варианта. Вариант с type='text' у меня работает - для текстового поля вызывается.

Пробовал turbolinks отключать - удалял гем и удалял required из application.js

Размещал код вызова функции `datepicker()` на элемент непосредственно в представлении - получал в консоли браузера ошибку, что `datepicker()` не является функцией.

Пробовал использовать datepicker из jquery-ui - тот же результат.

Дело, видимо, не в том, что вызываю, а как.

Comment: Причесал текст. Удостоверьтесь, пожалуйста, что ничего не потерял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что не верно вызывал методы плагинов.
Нужно было так:

```coffee
ready = ->
  $('.clockpicker').clockpicker()
  //                           ++
  $('.datepicker-inline').datepicker()
  //                                ++
$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready)
```